# ObjectOutputStream hangs forever

Tags: java, sockets

I have a client that connects to a server using sockets.  Sometimes  the write object method below hangs.  Do you have any ideas ?

```
public void writeObject(Object obj) throws IOException, NullPointerException {
    if(obj instanceof CMSRequestMessage)
        CMSLogger.interfaceDebugLogger.info("Starting Method  writeObject for transID ["
                                        + ((CMSRequestMessage)obj).getTransID() + "] ");
    objectOutputStream.writeObject(obj);
    objectOutputStream.flush();
    objectOutputStream.reset();

    CMSLogger.interfaceDebugLogger.info("End Method  writeObject for transID ["
           + ((CMSRequestMessage)obj).getTransID() + "] "); // never reaches here 
}
```

Comment: Is the other endpoint disconnected, sending RSTs, FINs, or any form of NACK? You can check this with a packet sniffer such as Wireshark.

Comment: Is the other end reading? If it isn't, writes to the socket will eventually block.

Comment: Also, please don't use "text speak".  Write proper english on stack overflow.  I'll edit this question for you.

Comment: thnx EJP  , the  other point was stopped  :)